# Как изменить порядок выбора элементов при помощи Tab?

Tags: qt5, pyqt5

[image: рис]

Элементы при помощи <kbd>Tab</kbd> выбираются так:

> Содержание пит.веществ -> Эн.ценность -> Углеводы -> Белки -> Жиры

Я хочу что бы выбирались так:

> Содержание пит.веществ -> Белки -> Жиры -> Углеводы -> Эн.ценность

При помощи чего это можно сделать?

Comment: Поищите в документации свойство `tabOrder`

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает! Делайте ответом и я помечу